# What is the expected change of the purchasing game?

Tags: probability, expectation, markov-chains, dynamic-programming

Denote the price of item as $N$ cents. The player has infinite coin supply of $1$, $5$, $10$ or $25$ cents. The player keeps drawing one coin of these four types with equal probability, until accumulated value reaches $N$ or beyond.

Question 1: What is the expected change the player could have for $N = 30$?

For example, if the player keeps drawing until he/she has $29$ cents. He/she draws another $5$ cent. Then he/she keeps the change of $4$ cents.
(My thought: for small $N$, such as $N = 30$, we might use Markov chain and solve all adsorbing state probabilities by hand. However, this is unpleasant.)

Question 2: What if the $N$ goes really large?

Comment: There is a useful recursion...If $p_n$ is the probability that your total equals $n$ at some point then $p_n=.25\times (p_{n-25}+p_{n-10}+p_{n-5}+p_{n-1})$ where $p_i=0$ for $i<0$, $p_0=1$.  Working with that should resolve your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer Question $2$ on the limit of the expected change as $N\to\infty$.

In a quasisteady state, the process is expected to progress by the average coin value $\frac{1+5+10+25}4=\frac{41}4$ in each step. It follows that each sum has probability $\frac4{41}$ of being attained at some point. Also, since all coins are equiprobable, a sum that is attained at some point is equally likely to be attained by any of the coins.

This, together with linearity of expectation, allows you to sum up the expected change contributions from the sums exceeding $N$. If an attainable final value $N\le v\le N+24$ can be reached with $k$ different coins before the game ends, it contributes $\frac k4\cdot\frac4{41}(v-N)=\frac k{41}(v-N)$ to the change.

The sum $N$ can be reached with any coin value, but it contributes $0$ change.

The $4$ sums $N+1$ through $N+4$ can be reached with the three coin values $5$, $10$ and $25$, so they contribute $\frac3{41}\sum_{k=1}^4k=\frac{30}{41}$.

The $5$ sums $N+5$ through $N+9$ can be reached with the two coin values $10$ and $25$, so they contribute $\frac2{41}\sum_{k=5}^9k=\frac{70}{41}$.

The $15$ sums $N+10$ through $N+24$ can be reached with the one coin value $25$, so they contribute $\frac1{41}\sum_{k=10}^{24}k=\frac{255}{41}$.

So the total expected change in the limit $N\to\infty$ is $\frac{30+70+255}{41}=\frac{355}{41}\approx8.66$.

I really do have to share my favourite change joke with you at this point:

A Zen monk orders chips (or, in US-American: fries). The vendor asks: “With ketchup or mayonnaise?” The Zen monk replies: “Make me one with everything.” Afterwards, the Zen monk pays and says: “Where's my change?” The vendor replies: “Change comes from within.”

Comment: Simulation says you are correct. Let me read it through.

Comment: Brilliant! What is your intuition at the beginning?

Comment: @YiBao: How do you mean? The intuition underlying the beginning of the post, or what my intuition was at the beginning of thinking about the problem?

Comment: I would say the intuition underlying the beginning of the post.

Comment: @YiBao: I think the key is to find and use the linear features. The process is quite complex; the probabilities to land on different values aren't independent; the only chance of solving it without going through the whole Markov or recurrence rigmarole is if we can leverage linearity of expectation. Stationary processes have nice average equilibrium properties, even if their details are complex. If you progress at an average rate $\lambda$, you spend an average time $\lambda^{-1}$ per value, independent of the details of the process, so that must be the probability of attaining a value.

Comment: @YiBao: A nice and useful result related to this that perhaps illustrates the intuition some more is that if you perform a random walk on a connected graph with $n$ edges, where in each step you uniformly randomly choose one of the neighbours of the current vertex to go to, then the average time spent per edge is $n^{-1}$, and so the average time spent at a vertex is the degree of the vertex over twice the number of edges, and the expected time of return from the vertex to itself is the reciprocal of that.

Comment: @YiBao:  This is true even if the walk is periodic and thus doesn't converge to the equilibrium distribution with probability $n^{-1}$ on each vertex. [Here's an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2830190) where I used that fact, also, like here, to avoid having to use the heavy Markov machinery.

Comment: @YiBao: The same simplicity and linearity apply to the probability of arriving at a value with a certain coin. That probability is correlated in complicated ways with the corresponding probabilities of neighbouring values, but since there are equally many "outgoing edges" for all coins, there must also be equally many "incoming edges" for all coins, so, independent of the details of the joint distributions, the marginal probability of arriving at any given value must be the same for all coins. The rest is just the magic of linearity of expectation :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for all these helpful comments, joriki!

Comment: @YiBao: Sorry, where it says "probability $n^{-1}$ on each vertex", it should say "on each edge".